# How can I access one desktop session from another on the same machine?

Tags: remote-desktop, localhost

I want to run a desktop session as user A, and from that session access a different desktop session as user B. This way I can test, screencast or share my screen from session B, while having access to apps/resources in session A that I do not want running/visible in session B. What application can I do this with?

I assume some kind of a remote desktop client/server is what I'm looking for. So far I have tried:

- **VNC.** Logged in as user A and user B. In session B run Desktop Sharing. Switched to session A. Tried to access share with Remmina. Failed. (Can get image to appear but it's frozen.)
- **x2go.** Installed server and client from [stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~x2go/+archive/stable) ([needed a workaround for installation to succeed](http://john.wesorick.com/2011/11/issues-installing-x2go.html)). Created a connection which starts then fails instantly. Discovered [mailing list post suggesting that accessing localhost is not supported](https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/x2go-user/2011-October/000469.html).
- On the non-remote front: **VirtualBox.** Created a minimal virtual machine for session B. Too resource heavy.

Am I attempting the impossible? Should I be looking for something other than a remote desktop tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using X2Go should work, actually. I see no reason why it shouldn't.

However, I would not recommend using a terminal server for this. I think it would be much better to use a nested X server, such as Xephyr.

Comment: thanks - using this script I can get a single application running in a xephyr window http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6870558&postcount=33 - how would I get an entire unity desktop running?

Comment: I think I'm looking for an up-to-date (11.10) version of http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10881343&postcount=3

Comment: You can use 'gnome-session --session=ubuntu' for  Unity or 'gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d' for unity2d

Comment: hmm, still struggling so I've opened a new question about that http://askubuntu.com/questions/116936/how-can-i-run-a-unity-session-inside-xephyr - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!