# How can I run a Unity session inside Xephyr?

Tags: unity, session

I can get Xephyr to run single applications within a Xephyr window. How can I run an entire Unity desktop session within a Xephyr window? (Preferably as another user.)

If I use the [gtk-xephyr](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6870558&postcount=33) script with the command `gnome-session --session=ubuntu`, I get a black window. If I run `compiz` I get a grey window.

If I do not use the script and just run the following I get a popup in the Xephyr window saying "Could not acquire name on session bus. [Log out]" and in the terminal "gnome-session[3157]: WARNING: Failed to acquire org.gnome.SessionManager".

```
Xephyr :8 &
DISPLAY=:8 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably as close as you are going to get.

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=3816948) Very informative

and

[Dedoimedo](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/xephyr.html) Nice graphics

Hope this helps

Comment: these are helpful, but don't resolve the issues above I'm afraid, I guess I'm looking for something more explicit